# Convert an element into textarea with css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have found a `<div>` element with class of `.plainMail` in a webpage and I want to be able to select all its text by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

I use Firefox 22. I was thinking about to turn the `div.plainMail` into a textarea. What can I do?

#### Update:

Can it be done via `document.getElementsByClassName`? because with `document.getElementById` I cannot do it. I use use GreaseMonkey.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you're exactly looking for, but you probably need HTML [Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fupizafe/2/edit)**.

By using JavaScript, you could add the attribute/value to the element as follows:

```javascript
var d = document.getElementById("myelement"); 
d.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true"); // Or: d.contentEditable = "true";
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fupizafe/4/edit)**.

> Can it be done via document.getElementsByClassName?

Sure *(if you don't care about IE8 and below)*, but note that [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a *NodeList* of matching elements, not a *single* element.

Thus, we have to loop through the returned list to apply the attribute, as follows:

```javascript
var i,
    list = document.getElementsByClassName("content");

for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fupizafe/11/edit)**.

Comment: Can it be done via document.getElementsByClassName?
because with document.getElementById I cannot do it.
The ID of .plainMail is a random number. I am using GreaseMonkey, is that OK?

Comment: @Sam-Bo I've updated the answer, added another demo to fit your needs.

Comment: How can I do it for several elements?
Must I use several scripts for each "ClassName"?
Maybe .getElementsByClassName("ONE").getElementsByClassName("TWO")

Comment: In order to select multiple classes, you could use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) method as `document.querySelectorAll(".myClass, .anotherClass");`. Here is the **[Updated Demo](http://jsbin.com/fupizafe/13/edit)**

Comment: @Sam-Bo Since the question has been closed, please consider adding more details and clarifying the question to reopen that. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

while Googling I found this link. seems very nearest as per this question.

following css code can give a textarea effect to the div.

```
#div-textarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
}
```

`http://blog.thinkingstiff.com/2012/01/22/how-to-make-a-contenteditable-look-like-an-element-or/`

also think link contains this fiddle link..

http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/FcCgA/

Comment: The `appearance` property only changes the default visual style of the element (base on the browser). it doesn't implement the *selectable* feature. In fact, you have used `contenteditable` attribute to achieve the that.